Why does a changed Python code in VSC sometimes not update until I completely restart VSC?
I started having this issue around a week ago:
When i change/add something in my Python code and run it in the VSC terminal, the program often ignores the new change and runs the older code, without the new addition. The change often occurs only after I restart VS Code.
Now this problem doesn't happen 100% of the time, sometimes everything works well right after i make a change in the code (btw, i have autosave on in vsc), but i still need to restart vsc often which is pretty annoying to do and it slows down the coding. Has anyone ever had an issue like that? And if so, has anyone managed to fix it?

Have you changed the "Auto Save Delay" setting at all? Is there a chance you're quitting VS Code before it has a chance to save your changes? Or, alternatively, do you have Auto Save set to "On Focus Change" or "On Window Change" (which may also cause it not to trigger)?

The autosave delay was set to 1000ms, i just tried set it to 500ms and the issue doesnt happen anymore thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is a delay in VSCode autosave files, you can set it by modifying files.autoSaveDelay in your settings.json.
For example, to set a delay of 500 milliseconds (0.5 second), you can add the following to your settings.json:
{
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 500
}

This setting controls the delay after which files are automatically saved.
